# Return future date - Javascript (year, month, day)

Tags: javascript, date

I have been trying to work this challenge for a while. It is finally working with a past date, it gives me the format that I want (year, month, days), but is not working with future dates. How can I rework this example, so it will also work with future dates? as of now I get an empty string.

```js
function reworkedInBetweenDays(year, month, day) {

   var today = new Date();

   var fromdate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

   var yearsDiff = today.getFullYear() - fromdate.getFullYear();
   var monthsDiff = today.getMonth() - fromdate.getMonth();
   var daysDiff = today.getDate() - fromdate.getDate();

   if (monthsDiff < 0 || (monthsDiff === 0 && daysDiff < 0))
      yearsDiff--;
   if (monthsDiff < 0)
      monthsDiff += 12;

   if (daysDiff < 0) {
      var fromDateAux = fromdate.getDate();
      fromdate.setMonth(fromdate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      daysDiff = fromdate.getDate() - fromDateAux + today.getDate();
      monthsDiff--;
   }

   var result = [];

   if (yearsDiff > 0)
      result.push(yearsDiff + (yearsDiff > 1 ? " years" : " year"));
   if (monthsDiff > 0)
      result.push(monthsDiff + (monthsDiff > 1 ? " months" : " month"));
   if (daysDiff > 0)
      result.push(daysDiff + (daysDiff > 1 ? " days" : " day"));

   return result.join(', ');

}

console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2013, 4, 8));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2014, 1, 16));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2016, 1, 31));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2017, 2, 16));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `Math.abs()` to getting your `yearsDiff`

```
function reworkedInBetweenDays(year, month, day) {

   var today = new Date();

   var fromdate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

   var yearsDiff = Math.abs(today.getFullYear() - fromdate.getFullYear()); //HERE
   var monthsDiff = today.getMonth() - fromdate.getMonth();
   var daysDiff = today.getDate() - fromdate.getDate();

   if (monthsDiff < 0 || (monthsDiff === 0 && daysDiff < 0))
      yearsDiff--;
   if (monthsDiff < 0)
      monthsDiff += 12;

   if (daysDiff < 0) {
      var fromDateAux = fromdate.getDate();
      fromdate.setMonth(fromdate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      daysDiff = fromdate.getDate() - fromDateAux + today.getDate();
      monthsDiff--;
   }

   var result = [];

   if (yearsDiff > 0)
      result.push(yearsDiff + (yearsDiff > 1 ? " years" : " year"));
   if (monthsDiff > 0)
      result.push(monthsDiff + (monthsDiff > 1 ? " months" : " month"));
   if (daysDiff > 0)
      result.push(daysDiff + (daysDiff > 1 ? " days" : " day"));

   return result.join(', ');

}

console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2013, 4, 8));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2014, 1, 16));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2016, 1, 31));
console.log(reworkedInBetweenDays(2017, 2, 16));
```

Comment: Thanks Yoplaboom, that did the trick! will accept your answer once I am able to.

Answer (score 1):

It works adding this code at the end

```
if (yearsDiff < 0)
  result.push(yearsDiff*(-1) + (yearsDiff*(-1) > 1 ? " years in the future" : " year in the future"));
if (monthsDiff < 0)
  result.push(monthsDiff*(-1) + (monthsDiff*(-1) > 1 ? " months in the future" : " month in the future"));
if (daysDiff < 0)
  result.push(daysDiff*(-1) + (daysDiff*(-1) > 1 ? " days in the future" : " day  in the future"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`monthsDiff` and `daysDiff` are both zero and `yearsDiff` is -1, meaning none of them set off the if statements at the bottom. You need to add some code to handle when all these values are zero or negative.